# Can mouseenter be made to not fire in IE on DOMready?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, mouseenter, domready

jQuery [emulates IE's mouseenter event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) on non-IE browsers. In IE, however, mouseenter is being triggered when the page loads (maybe due to jQuery's use of `doScroll` in the `$.ready` implementation), even if the mouse is not moved at all.

This doesn't happen in other browsers and definitely doesn't follow [Microsoft's own spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which says (emphasis mine):

> The event fires only if the mouse pointer is outside the boundaries of the object and the user **moves** the mouse pointer inside the boundaries of the object. If the mouse pointer is currently inside the boundaries of the object, for the event to fire, the **user must move** the mouse pointer outside the boundaries of the object and then back inside the boundaries of the object.

This only becomes an issue of usability if hover (or the hoverIntent plugin) is applied to a navigational item to display a drop down or "mega-menu": In IE, mouseenter will fire immediately after `$.ready`, obscuring the content with the menu.

Comment: Been looking for this answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one working solution: Do the binding in a later thread:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        /* bind with hoverIntent */
    }, 0);
});
```

In the past this has fixed so many IE problems for me (form elements not being ready) that jQuery should bake it in to `$.ready`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the binding on the first mousemove event, rather than on DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).one('mousemove', function() { // only on the first time the mouse is moved
        $('#yourMenu').mouseenter(function() { // bind the mouseenter code
            // your code
        });
    });
});
```

It's a little hacky, but I think it should work.

---

I like the solution of using `setTimeout`.  One other solution *may* be to do the binding on `$(window).load()` instead:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#yourMenu').mouseenter(function() { // bind the mouseenter code
        // your code
    });
});
```

Comment: See the "Added" note. mousemove gets fired on $.ready() on every element I attached it to.